# Specify nesting columns by using character vector in tidyr::complete

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, tidyr

How can I define the columns I want to use for nesting in the tidyr::complete function?

`one_of` or `as.name` are not working.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- tibble(
  group = c(1:2, 1),
  item_id = c(1:2, 2),
  item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
  value1 = 1:3,
  value2 = 4:6
)
char_vec <- c("item_id", "item_name")
df %>% complete(group, nesting(char_vec))

Error: `by` can't contain join column `char_vec` which is missing from RHS
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1):

An up to date solution with dplyr version 1.06 is `!!!syms()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    complete(group, nesting(!!!syms(char_vec)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- tibble(
  group = c(1:2, 1),
  item_id = c(1:2, 2),
  item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
  value1 = 1:3,
  value2 = 4:6
)
char_vec <- c("item_id", "item_name")
df %>% complete(group, nesting(!!as.symbol(char_vec)))
```

Comment: When using right_join(ds, complete(ds, !!as.ymbol(vars)) a different data set, I get slightly less rows using !!.asymbol compared to instead inserting variables manually or using !!!syms(char_vec). I am unsure why this is happening, but thought I should let you know that it may not be working as intended in this situation.